# How to properly return a promise from an angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not getting the array of customers back from the angular service.

Service:

```
surchargeIndex.service('customerService', [
    "$http", function ($http) {
        this.get = function (customerType) {
            if (customerType == "1") {
                getProduction().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
            } else if (customerType == "2") {
                getTest().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
            } else {
                getAll().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
            }
        }
 var getTest = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
        })
             .success(function (data) {
                 return data;
             });
    };

    var getProduction = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetProduction",
        })
             .success(function (data) {
                 return data;
             });
    };

    var getAll = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetAll",
        })
             .success(function (data) {
                 return data;
             });
    };
```

Controller Call:

```
$scope.getCustomers = function(customerType) {
        $scope.showContent = false;
        $scope.customers = customerService.get(customerType);
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerController" data-ng-init="init()" class="col-md-2">
    <select ng-model="customerKey" ng-options="customer.Key as customer.Value for customer in customers"></select>
</div>
```

The call is being made to the server every time; however, the select list isn't being populated.

Comment: Can you post `getProduction()`, `getTest()` and `getAll()` so we can see what you are returning? If you are wanting to return from `this.get()` then you can just return the $http method and chain onto it `return $http().then()..... something().then().then()`

Comment: Why most people do not use $resource? :sad:

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807592/angular-js-promise-in-service-not-updating-view?rq=1 -- your problem is that you're binding the promise instead of binding its results, and the solution is to attach your binding code to the returned promise's `then` handler.

Comment: @Rytmis I have my code bound to the promise's then handler. I am not sure that question is the same as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the return statement to the CustomerService get method and also remove the success functions which you have written in the getAll(), getProduction(), getTest() methods

```
surchargeIndex.service('customerService', [
    "$http", function ($http) {
        this.get = function (customerType) {
            var promise;
            if (customerType == "1") {
                promise = getProduction().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
            } else if (customerType == "2") {
                promise = getTest().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
            } else {
                promise = getAll().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
            }
            return promise;
        }
    var getTest = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
        });

    };

    var getProduction = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetProduction",
        });
    };

    var getAll = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetAll",
        });
    };
```

controller

```
$scope.getCustomers = function(customerType) {
        $scope.showContent = false;
        customerService.get(customerType).then(function(data) {
                         $scope.customers = data;
        });
    };
```

Comment: This still doesn't populate the select list.

Comment: @Robert this edit for the controller code is what I meant above when I said about the `then` handler.

Comment: @Rytmis so there should be two promises. one in the controller and one in the service?

Comment: Think of it this way: in JavaScript, you cannot make an asynchronous api behave as if it were synchronous. In practice, if your service depends on an asynchronous API, it must also expose an asynchronous API. Once you add the `return` to your `get` function, your `customerSerivice` is already returning a promise (in a success case, the promise will be resolved whatever you return in the `then` handler of the `$http` request). Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Add more `return`s

```
surchargeIndex.service('customerService', [
"$http", function ($http) {
    this.get = function (customerType) {
        if (customerType == "1") {
            return getProduction().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
            ^^^^^^
        } else if (customerType == "2") {
            return getTest().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
        } else {
            return getAll().then(function (result) { return result.data; });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The list is not being populated even with the added returns